# How to generate unique numbers for list items

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a long list of values in a file called `list.txt` and I want to generate a random unique number for each item within the file text file. if the item appears more than once it will have the same unique id

for example the `list.txt` would be:

```
may-111
may-111
rob-222
kim-456
may-111
```

I want to be able to assign a random number to each item. If the item appears more than once then it will have the same unique ID number, therefore the expected output should be:-

```
may-111 - 789
may-111 - 789
rob-222 - 365
kim-456 - 641
may-111 - 789
```

I have tried generating a list of random numbers and save to a new text file and  then `paste` or `join` the new text file to the `list.txt` :

```
paste -d list.txt random.txt
```

Currently the output doesn't keep the unique ID and if the same name appears more than once it has a different ID.

Comment: Do you want this to be an awk script?

Comment: Do you want the numbers to be random or unique? Either thing is trivial to do but to try to do both might result in a script that runs for months waiting for the random number generator to come up with a number that hasn't already been used..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this awk:

```
awk '!seen[$1]{seen[$1] = rand() * 1000000} {print $0 " - " seen[$1]}' file
may-111 - 840188
may-111 - 840188
rob-222 - 394383
kim-456 - 783099
may-111 - 840188
```

- `rand()` is function to generate a random number like `0.840188`
- `seen` is an associative array with key as `$1` and value as a random number
- `!seen[$1]` - Execute this block for key not in array `seen`
- `seen[$1] = rand() * 1000000` - Populate array with `key=$1` and `value=rand()`
- `{print $0 " - " seen[$1]}` - Print current line and stored random value for key `$1` from array.

---

**EDIT:** (Thanks to JID) One can use this awk command to avoid repetition of numbers:

```
awk '!seen[$0]{do{x=int(rand()*1000);seen[$0]=x}while(nums[x])} 
     {print $0, "-", seen[$0]}' ile
may-111 - 840
may-111 - 840
rob-222 - 394
kim-456 - 783
may-111 - 840
```

Comment: This could generate the same random number twice for different keys.

Comment: Well random is never truly random isn't it. For seizable # of records it will work but after huge # of records it might repeat.

Comment: Also see **EDIT** section for alternate approach.

Comment: Here is a way with rand without repeated random numbers `awk '!a[$0]{do{x=int(rand()*1000);a[$0]=x}while(b[x])}{print $0,a[$0]}' file`

Comment: The error is more serious than it might first appear -- it analogous to the birthday problem. With this set of 1000000 random numbers, the chance that a duplicate will be generated first exceeds 50% when 1178 unique identifiers are requested. That is not a lot of identifiers, and 50% is a *very* high probability in the context.

Comment: I tried the first answer I got tons of repeated number.

Comment: @JID: Many thanks for your suggestion. I believe that will work. (Have edited my answer to include it)

Comment: @MikeyR: Check edited answer for improved command based on JID's suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

You can create an identifier being the number of the line in which it appears for the first time:

```
$ awk '{if ($1 in a) {c=a[$1]} else {c=NR; a[$1]=c}} {print $1, c}' file
may-111 1
may-111 1
rob-222 3
kim-456 4
may-111 1
```

This way, you don't get any repeated value.

More idiomatic ([thanks to JID's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27986734/how-to-generate-unique-numbers-for-list-items/27986862?noredirect=1#comment44365270_27986862)):

```
awk '{!a[$0]&&a[$0]=NR}{print $0,a[$0]}' file
```

#### Explanation

This stores the ids in an array `a[]`, so that every time we read a line we cross check if it already has a defined associated value.

- `{if (...) {action if true} else {action if false}`
- `{if ($1 in a) {c=a[$1]} else {c=NR; a[$1]=c}}` get the associated value from the first time we read the line. If it is not the case, fetch the stored value.
- `print $1, c` print the content together with the identifier.

You can of course tune it:

- For a different output separator, use `-v OFS=" - "`, for example.
- For a bigger associated value, sum or multiply or whatever to something constant.

Comment: I saw a comment that flew away : (

Comment: This is a little shorter `awk '{!a[$0]&&a[$0]=NR}{print $0,a[$0]}' file`. Also the other comment was mine but it was wrong :)

Comment: @JID Kudos for your suggestion, it is way more idiomatic and I like it. With your permission, I add it to my current solution. Many thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad you like it :)